# How to match the keys of two dictionaries encapsulated within a list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.7

I have two dictionaries which is there within a list. The list looks like this [{'10.1.1.0':[1], '10.1.1.1':[2]}, {'10.1.1.0':[3], '10.1.1.1':[4]}]. What I need is for the same keys i.e. the matching ips I want the corresponding number or value.

- So the sample output looks like this [{'10.1.1.0':[1], '10.1.1.0':[3]}, {'10.1.1.1':[2], '10.1.1.1':[4]}]

Is this possible? Any help would be really appricaiated.

Comment: A dictionary can't have multiple entries with the same key, so your desired output isn't possible with a `dict` object, though you might be able to get somewhat close with some other data structure. Are you sure you don't want to merge the lists that are the values of the dictionaries (e.g. `{'10.1.1.0': [1, 3], '10.1.1.1': [2, 4]}`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not possible with a dictionary in Python. Duplicate keys [are not allowed](https://realpython.com/python-dicts/#restrictions-on-dictionary-keys). Instead you could have the same key mapped to multiple values in a list:

```py
x = [{'10.1.1.0': [1], '10.1.1.1': [2]}, {'10.1.1.0': [3], '10.1.1.1': [4]}]
new_dict = dict() # initialize a new dictionary
for d in x: # iterate over the original list of dictionaries
    for k, v in d.items(): # get all the items in the current dictionary
        if k in new_dict: # add the key and value, or add the value to a key
            new_dict[k] += v
        else:
            new_dict[k] = v
print(new_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'10.1.1.0': [1, 3], '10.1.1.1': [2, 4]}
```