# How to merge 2 dictionaries in python 3.7 and get a list if there are multiple values per key

Tags: python

I have the following 2 dictionaries:

```py
dict_1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'e': 5}
dict_2 = {'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 7}
```

I want to merge them so the result is:

```py
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': [5,7]}
```

Where the order of the list is important, so dict_1 merged with dict_2 should get 'e': [5,7] and dict_2 merged with dict_1 should get 'e': [7,5]

Comment: and what have you tried ?

Comment: Add both key sets to a combined set and then iterate it.

Comment: [Sort of related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68524456/how-to-match-the-keys-of-two-dictionaries-encapsulated-within-a-list-in-python/68524518#68524518)

Comment: Are you sure that you want a resulting dict in which the values are sometimes ints, sometimes lists, rather than always lists that may contain only one item or more?

Answer (score 2):

Iterate on the second dict and apply the logic : new pair or list

```
result = {**dict_1}
for k, v in dict_2.items():
    if k in result:
        result[k] = [result[k], v]
    else:
        result[k] = v

# final sorting
result = {k: result[k] for k in sorted(result)}
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved with a classical nested loop, and is generalizable to an arbitrary number of dictionaries:

```
dict_1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'e': 5}
dict_2 = {'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 7}

out = {}

for d in [dict_1, dict_2]:
    for k,v in d.items():
        if k in out:
            if isinstance(out[k], list):
                out[k].append(v)
            else:
                out[k] = [out[k], v]
        else:
            out[k] = v
out
```

Output:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'e': [5, 7], 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
```

*NB. The **keys** will be in order of appearance, if needed you can sort them afterwards. The **values** are in the desired order*

Comment: The `isinstance` check isn't necessary; the only way `out[k]` could be a list is if it already got a value from both dictionaries.  This check would be needed, however, if more than 2 dictionaries were being merged.

Comment: @Scott that's what I had in mind (could be premature optimization :p)

Comment: This was exactly what I needed, especially since I was planning on merging 3 dictionaries

Answer (score 2):

Try with this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def merge_dict(x,y):
    dd = defaultdict(list)

    for d in (x, y): # you can list as many input dicts as you want here
        for key, value in d.items():
            dd[key].append(value)

    dd = dict(sorted(dd.items()))

    return dd
```

Test

```
x = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'e': 5}
y = {'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 7}

print(merge_dict(x,y))

out: {'a': [1], 'b': [2], 'c': [3], 'd': [4], 'e': [5, 7]}

print(merge_dict(y,x))

out: {'a': [1], 'b': [2], 'c': [3], 'd': [4], 'e': [7, 5]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def combined(d1, d2):
    commons = {key: [d1[key], d2[key]] for key in (key for key in d1 if key in d2)}
    return {**d1, **d2, **commons}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
def update_dictionary(dict_, to_be_update_dict):
    for k, v in dict_.items():
        if to_be_update_dict.get(k) != None:
            to_be_update_dict[k] = to_be_update_dict[k] + [v]
        else:
            to_be_update_dict[k] = [v]


dict_3 = {}

update_dictionary(dict_1,dict_3)

update_dictionary(dict_2,dict_3)

dict_3
Out[114]: {'a': [1], 'b': [2], 'e': [5, 7], 'c': [3], 'd': [4]}
```

And to sort the dictionary by its keys

```
sorted_dict = dict(sorted(dict_3.items()))

{'a': [1], 'b': [2], 'c': [3], 'd': [4], 'e': [5, 7]}
```